# is dense feedforward network a deep neural network?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, terminology

Feed forward neural network  do they belong to deep neural network or ANN?

[image]

I have a doubt whether to call my frame work as deep neural network or a artificial neural network

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about DL theory and/or methodology - please see the NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/deep-learning/info

Answer (score 1):

FFN refers to neural networks in which information flows into one direction only, as opposed to Recurrent Network for instance where information can flow back form the previous time steps.

An FFN is a type of ANN. "Deep" usually means several layers stacked. A one layer ANN would usually be qualified as "Shallow".